# Problemas con levantar Ventana de busqueda en JAVA

Tags: java, java-swing, java-8

Tengo una pantalla de **ABM** de Personas (JinternalFrame). Uno de los campos de la pantalla es "Ciudad". En el mismo al presionar F3 llamo una pantalla de búsqueda genérica (`Jframe`) de la siguiente forma:

```
if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_F3) {

    Buscador.Buscar_tabla("CIUDAD", "DESCIUDAD", "CODCIUDAD", "NROCIUDAD", "Buscar Ciudad", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "");



    if (Buscador.campo_clave_tablas != "0") {
            txtCiudad.setText(Buscador.campo_numero_tablas);
            lblDesCiudad.setText(Buscador.campo_descripcion_tablas);
    }       
}
```

Como ven el método `Buscar_tabla` es un método estático de la clase Buscador, de la siguiente manera:

```
public static void Buscar_tabla(String nombre_tabla, String nombre_campo_descripcion, String nombre_campo_codigo, 
        String nombre_campo_numcodigo, String titulo_pantalla, String where, String group_by, String having, 
        String opCampo1, String opCampo1Text, String opCampo2, String opCampo2Text, String opCampo3, 
        String opCampo3Text,String opCampo4, String opCampo4Text, String primerasPalabras) {


    frmBuscar ventana = new frmBuscar();

    campo_clave_tablas = "0";
    campo_numero_tablas = "0";
    campo_descripcion_tablas = "0";
    campo1_clave = "0";
    campo2_clave = "0";
    campo3_clave = "0";
    campo4_clave = "0";

    ventana.CodigoBus = nombre_campo_codigo;
    ventana.NumCodigoBus = nombre_campo_numcodigo;
    ventana.DescripcionBus = nombre_campo_descripcion;
    ventana.NombretablaBus = nombre_tabla;

    ventana.titulo_Buscador = titulo_pantalla;

    ventana.sentencia_where = where;
    ventana.group_by = group_by;
    ventana.having = having;
    ventana.opCampo1 = opCampo1;
    ventana.opCampo2 = opCampo2;
    ventana.opCampo3 = opCampo3;
    ventana.opCampo4 = opCampo4;
    ventana.opCampo1Text = opCampo1Text;
    ventana.opCampo2Text = opCampo2Text;
    ventana.opCampo3Text = opCampo3Text;
    ventana.opCampo4Text = opCampo4Text;
    ventana.primerasPalabras = primerasPalabras;

    ventana.setVisible(true);

    if (Main.SeleccionBusquedaOK == true) {
        campo_clave_tablas = Integer.toString(Main.CodigoBusQuedaResultado);
        campo_numero_tablas = Main.NroCodigoBusquedaResultado;
        campo_descripcion_tablas = Main.DescripcionBusquedaResultado;

        Main.SeleccionBusquedaOK = false;
    }
```

Como ven, el método instancia una clase `Jframe` pasandole los parámetros.
 Una vez mostrado la pantalla, procedo a elegir el registro deseado del `Jtable` de la misma y los guardo en variables globales. (`codigo`, `nrocodigo` y `descripcion`).

El problema es que cuando la linea de ejecución se ubica en `ventana.setVisible(true);`, muestra la pantalla pero sigue con la linea siguiente..

Pues, lo que necesito es que recién una vez que se cierre la pantalla de búsqueda (al seleccionar un registro de la misma), continúe con el bloque de:

```
if (Main.SeleccionBusquedaOK == true) {
        campo_clave_tablas = Integer.toString(Main.CodigoBusQuedaResultado);
        campo_numero_tablas = Main.NroCodigoBusquedaResultado;
        campo_descripcion_tablas = Main.DescripcionBusquedaResultado;

        Main.SeleccionBusquedaOK = false;
    }
```

De esa manera setear lo seleccionado de la búsqueda al `txtCiudad` y `lblDescripcionCiudad` de mi pantalla de Personas.

¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas considerar estos pasos:

1.Necesitas crearte un JPanel para agregar tus componentes como ser JFields y JButton, etc. y cuando haya una acción del usuario necesitas agregar un ActionListener de modo que el usuario hizo click sobre el boton buscar.

```
 JFrame frame = new JFrame();
 JPanel panel = new JPanel();
 JButton button = new JButton("buscar");
 button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

 @Override
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      campo_clave_tablas = Integer.toString(Main.CodigoBusQuedaResultado);
      campo_numero_tablas = Main.NroCodigoBusquedaResultado;
      campo_descripcion_tablas = Main.DescripcionBusquedaResultado;   
      Main.SeleccionBusquedaOK = false;
  }
 });

 panel.add(button);
 frame.add(frame);
```